# algaworks JSF Primefaces nao echerga metodos void

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

Estou  estudando PrimeFaces com CDI de algumas vídeo aulas que venho assistindo  mas tá acontecendo algo que no mínimo estranho .

Tenho um bean `gestaoEmpresas`

Lá tem dois métodos, um `void consultar()` e um `List<Empresas> todasEmpresas()`

Mas no meu XHTML não enxerga meu método `void` somente o método com retorno de  um `List` mas se mudar a tag e colocar em um `<h:commandButtum` por exemplo ele enxerga. Por exemplo :

//não enxerga o método consultar

```
<f:metadata>
<f:viewAction action="#{gestaoEmpresasBean.}" />
</f:metadata>
```

//não enxerga o método consultar

```
<p:commandButton action="#{gestaoEmpresasBean.}"/>
```

//enxerga o método consultar

```
<h:commandButton action="#{gestaoEmpresasBean.consultar}"/>
```

Não entendo porque ele não esta enxergando quando uso o faces ou o PrimeFaces